# Is it possible to communicate between different CIDRs?

Tags: networking, ip, cidr

For example, there are two CIDRs in the same VPC on AWS. One of them is public and one is private. They are in the different segment.

```
# Public Subnet CIDR
10.124.42.0/27

# Private Subnet CIDR
10.124.43.128/25
```

If want to connect from public to private's network, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, subnets in your VPC can communicate by default.

It is possible to provide a custom security configuration to control inbound/outbound traffic using Security Groups or Networl ACLs features.

It is also possible to configure routing using Route Tables.

Please refer to the [official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#SubnetSecurity), which covers this topics in detail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).